# Invoking specific methods based on Specific Constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to both save new records and update existing records using a single form
but with two constructors (one with parameters and the other without). The constructor that is called should determine which method should be invoked(Save or Update).

```
public ManageRecord(Record record ){ //update  record     }

public ManageRecord(){ //save new record     }

private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    //if default constructor invokes form call save method
    SaveMethod();
    //if constructor with parameters invokes form call update method
    UpdateMethod(record);
}
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Why did you choose to get constructors involved in this?

Comment: I'm sensing an XY problem here.  What are you really trying to accomplish with this?  Tell us your root problem and we can help you fix it the right way.

Comment: I'm going to *guess* that this is on a View Model.  You are trying to know if you should insert a new record, or update an existing based on the instance of the Model being new or not.  If that is correct, please let us know.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i'd be glad if you could guide me with a better method

Comment: @BradleyUffner i want to complete either tasks with the same form/window. and no its not in a view model. I'm a beginner and MVVM is not working well for me at the moment

Comment: @wsduho You need to read the question he asked, think about it, and answer *that* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past to solve this is to have the Primary Key field on the Model as a `Nullable` field.  When you try to save the record you can just look at the field on the Model, if `MyPk.HasValue` returns `true`, then you are updating a record, if it is `false`, you are inserting a new record.

When you call the constructor that takes an instance of model, just save it in a local field.  When the constructor without a model is called, create a new model instance with a null PK, and save it in the local field.  `Save` can just examine the local field.

So in the end, your action isn't directly based on which constructor was called, it should be based on the state of the model that you are currently working with.

Comment: Side note: you may want to higlight the fact there will be exactly one method to call in this case (like `SaveOrUpdate()` )

Comment: i thought of checking the id of the record that is passed by the constructor, i was only hoping there was a pre-established

Comment: i thought of checking the id of the record that is passed by the constructor, i was only hoping there was a pre-established or better method of achieving the same result

Comment: There is nothing built in.  You could always set a flag as in the answer @FrumRoll gave, but I feel that relying on the properties of the model is a far better way to do it. The model should always be there and be consistent.  If you set a flag from the constructor you will have to remember to set it if you ever add another constructor.  It might also cause you problems if you ever decide to implement dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a Boolean value in your constructor.

```
private readonly bool _isNewEntity;

public ManageRecord()
{
    _isNewEntity = true;
    // Same as existing, _record = new Record() ?
}

public ManageRecord(Record record)
{
    _isNewEntity = false;
    // Same as existing, _record = record ?
}

private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isNewEntity)
        SaveMethod();
    else
        UpdateMethod(record);
}
```